# second call of gethostbyname gives seg fault

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault

this piece of code **runs perfectly the first time it enters the loop**, the second time gives get seg fault, **if i run program..quit..run again, it works perfectly** too

```
if ((server=gethostbyname(HOSTA))==NULL){
    fprintf(stderr,"\n\tRESOLVE SERVER FAIL\n\n");
    exit(3);
}
```

bt in gdb gives

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x0012d422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0012d422 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0x00197681 in raise () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#2  0x0019aab2 in abort () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#3  0x001d124d in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#4  0x001db341 in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#5  0x001dcb98 in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#6  0x001dfc7d in free () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#7  0x001cb85a in fclose () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#8  0x002d0734 in ?? () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libnss_files.so.2
#9  0x002d1b9f in _nss_files_gethostbyname_r () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libnss_files.so.2
#10 0x002577de in gethostbyname_r () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#11 0x00257036 in gethostbyname () from /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
#12 0x0804a00c in update () at main.h:144
#13 0x0804b247 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff4a4) at main.c:78
(gdb) q
```

NOTE: i am a noob as a debugger

my interpretation is that im not **free**ing either on the struct hostent or the return of gethostbyname itself

code: [@pastebin](http://pastebin.com/x7492UCM)

**what am i doing wrong ?**

EDIT: function `update()` enters a loop

Comment: what are you free()ing?  Note that free()ing something twice is a major bug, which can result in the error you're seeing.

Comment: @user9876 im not free()ing nothing, my guess is that maybe i should free() something related, either with hostent struct or the return of gethostbyname(), if i run once->close program->run once->close program->run once.... it works perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant point out the exact problem either, but there are definitely some errors in the function. I noticed this:

```
  char *stringA;
  ....
   if((stringA=malloc(BUFSIZEE))==NULL){
            printf("\n\tMEMORY ERROR\n\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    stringA=build_get_query(HOSTA,page);
    if((write(sockfd,stringA,strlen(stringA)))<0){
            printf("\n\tERROR ON SEND\n\n");
    }
```

You are loosing the pointer (returned by malloc) stored in stringA when build_get_query returns some other address (presumably). And depending on the size and allocation method of the returned data, you can segfault if a) its not allocated dynamically b) freed somewhere else also c) differs in size from BUFSIZE (you memset stringA many times and use it as a BUFSIZE buffer).

**EDIT:** To clarify, "strings" i.e. character arrays, can not be copied in C by assignment. The function can return a pointer, but the return value can not fill the malloced area.

Comment: stringA is just a functional string thats stores different kinds of data along the program;

on that case stringA only receives a return string from build_get_query();

**how do i fill in char *stringA with return value from build_get_query()  ?**
a) the returned data is malloc()ed
b) it is not freed nowhere;
c) BUFSIZE is long enough to never cause trouble when manipulating stringA, memset is to prevent garbage inside stringA;

Comment: You can either give *stringA as a parameter to build_get_query, like `build_get_query(HOSTA,page stringA, BUFSIZE)` the last parameter tells the function how much space is available in stringA. The other way around, you can skip the malloc() in update() and malloc the memory inside build_get_query and return that pointer. In the latter case the assignment you have currently would achieve what you want.

Comment: My (far fetched) guess currently is that build_get_query returns some memory pointer related to HOSTA and the following string manipulations mess up that location, so that when gethostbyname is called, HOSTA does not contain a valid string. Just a guess.

Comment: not possible because `#define HOSTA "www.website.com"`
i was very carefull about `stringA` string manipulations to not screw the program flow

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some undefined behavior *elsewhere* in your program (e.g. a buffer overflow, inappropriate size for `malloc`, bad or missing call to `free`, ....)

Try to compile your program with `-Wall -g` (perhaps also `-Wextra`) and to use the `gdb` debugger and the [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) memory leak detector.

Notice that `gdb` has the `watch` command which may be very handy.

Also, [gethostbyname(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html) is documented as obsolete (and may return some pointer to static data). Use `getaddrinfo` instead.

Comment: i already am compiling with -Wall -g `CFLAGS = -g -O3 -ansi -pedantic -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`

Comment: changed makefile to `CFLAGS = -g -O0 -ansi -pedantic -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`

Comment: Remove `-O3`, add `-Wextra`. Use both `gdb` and `valgrind` (and perhaps `strace`)

Comment: $ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./euroms
==4562== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4562== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4562== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4562== Command: ./euroms
==4562== 
--4562-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x2a

valgrind: m_debuginfo/readdwarf.c:2292 (copy_convert_CfiExpr_tree): Assertion 'srcix >= 0 && srcix < VG_(sizeXA)(srcxa)' failed.
==4562==    at 0x380278E5: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=0
$

Comment: valgrind pointed warning `--4562-- Warning: DWARF2 CFI reader: unhandled DW_OP_ opcode 0x2a

valgrind: m_debuginfo/readdwarf.c:2292 (copy_convert_CfiExpr_tree): Assertion 'srcix >= 0 && srcix < VG_(sizeXA)(srcxa)' failed.
==4562==    at 0x380278E5: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-x86-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=0`